# Is it a foul when a player calls a wrong score in badminton?

Tags: rules, badminton

In one of our tournament double matches after earning a point one of the player mistakenly called the current game point wrong. Instead of saying 6-4 he said 7-4 and the referee didn't rectify it. Then on the next serve when the cork reached the other side one player on that side grabbed the cork and said it was a foul to call a wrong score.

My question:

1. Was it a foul to call a wrong game point?
2. Was it a foul that the other player grabbed the cork even though referee didn't call a foul?

Is there a reference URL or book to verify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *umpire* [(not the referee)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/13813/1419) is in charge of the scoring. Players can announce the score to their partner or even their opponents, but that is not binding in any way. It's hard to prove a negative, but you can peruse the [official Laws of Badminton](https://extranet.bwfbadminton.com/docs/document-system/81/1466/1470/Section%204.1%20-%20Laws%20of%20Badminton.pdf) and won't find any mention of a fault of incorrect scoring.

The following laws *could* apply to a talking player:

> §14.2.5 It shall be a fault if in play, a player deliberately distracts an opponent by any action such as shouting or making gestures;
> §16.6.3 A player shall not behave in an offensive or inappropriate manner.
> §16.6.4 A player shall not be guilty of misconduct not otherwise covered by the Laws of Badminton.

None of this applies: The shuttle wasn't even in play when the score was called, and it's neither offensive nor misconduct to make a mistake.

A case could be made if a player intentionally calls the wrong score all the time. However, even that would be dealt with by the umpire, not the opposing player. The umpire would show a yellow card (without any changes to the score) first. Awarding a point for a fault would be done by the umpire showing a red card, which requires serious misconduct.

Incorrect scoring by the players is no big deal: The umpire clearly announces the correct score after every rally. Usually there's some kind of scoreboard; at higher levels you'll find a TV at either end of the court displaying the current score in big letters. If the player thinks the umpire made a mistake, they can talk to the umpire before the start of the next rally.

However, the player who touched the shuttle *did* commit a fault:

> §13.3.4 It shall be a fault if in play, the shuttle touches the person or dress of a player.

Therefore, the umpire will call out "Fault. 7-4." and update the scoreboard (if any) to 7-4.

Comment: Additionally, it could not possibly be a foul, because fouls do not exist in badminton. There are faults, and there are warnings/cards for various forms of conduct, but the concept of a foul simply does not exist like it does in some other sports.